# Extracting specific string after specific character

Tags: python

```
new = ['mary 2jay 3ken +', 'mary 2jay 3ken +', 'steven +john ']
print(new):
mary 2jay 3ken +
mary 2jay 3ken +
steven +john  -
```

How could I get the sign/number after each person's name? I'm wondering whether `dict` would work in this case as my expected output is:

```
mary:2
jay:3
ken:+
steven:+
john:-
```

Comment: Did you try something? What is the expected result for the given list?

Comment: The output of `print` you posted is not the output we get.

Comment: What is the expected output for `new` in the question?

Comment: The `print` is just for your ease of reading. The expected output is mary: 2, jay: 3, ken: +, steven: +, john: . `dict` just come to my mind but not sure whether it is appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the index of "+" in a string, you can use:

```
index = a_string.index("+")
```

To check if "+" exist in a string, use:

```
if "+" in a_string:
    # ...
```

To iterate a list of string, you can do:

```
for text in new:
    # ...
```

There are fifty ways to do what you want. I suggest you to read the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator).

**edit**

You can use a RegEx to extract the fields name/number

```
for text in next:
    couples = re.findall(r"(\S+)\s+(\d+|\+|\-|$)", text)
    for name, num in couples:
        print(name, num)
```

Comment: appreciate that, but I think you have totally misunderstood my question.

Comment: @JAY.Y You can use a RegEx

Comment: Thank you, this is the first time to use re module.